# React | TypeError: this.state.cars.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show a list of car brands in react but i get this error. The Web API is tested and works fine.

> TypeError: this.state.cars.map is not a function

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class cars extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cars: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/fetchcars").then(res =>{
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({cars: res.data});
    });
  }

  render() {
      return(
          <ul>
              {this.state.cars.map(car => <li>{car.brand}</li>)}
          </ul>
      )
  }
}
```

**Response Output**

```
config: Object { url: "http://localhost:3000/api/fetchcars", method: "get", timeout: 0, … }
data: {…}
car: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
status: true
<prototype>: Object { … }
headers: Object { "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Comment: Can you share what you are getting in the `res` variable?

Comment: `res.data` is most likely an object

Comment: looks like maybe you need to set it to `res.car` instead of `res.data`

Comment: It's the json object

Comment: can you share how res.data looks like

Comment: Why did you delete the response example?

Comment: we need response example to understand your issue

Comment: @BrianThompson still same problem

Comment: {…}
​
config: Object { url: "http://localhost:3000/api/fetchcars", method: "get", timeout: 0, … }
​
data: {…}
​​
car: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​​
status: true
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
headers: Object { "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }

Comment: Use `this.setState({cars: res.data.car});` and see my answer below for an explanation of this error.

Comment: please update it in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will generally crop up because you're trying to map something that is not of the type array. Make sure you're actually mapping an array. If it is an array this crops up usually because the value you're expecting to map across is `undefined` or `null`. If that is the case, that is your problem, and you must check that the value exists before mapping it.

In this case you're targeting `res.data` which is an object, instead of the array which is `res.car`.

Comment: in his case it's actually `res.car`

Comment: Well spotted @DragoşPaulMarinescu